# Using a cursor in SQL Developer to generate a subsequent query for each record

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have an SQL Developer query in which I would like to use a cursor to generate subsequent select statements.

But, I'm doing something wrong.  I don't seem to be using the cursor correctly.

Here is my code thus far.  Thanks much.

```
DECLARE

  numMaterials  NUMBER := 0;

  CURSOR item_id_cur
      IS
       select id from item_h
       where value = 'myvalue';
                 
    l_item_id   item_id_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  OPEN item_id_cur;

  LOOP
    FETCH item_id_cur INTO l_item_id;
    EXIT WHEN item_id_cur%NOTFOUND;

    SELECT count(*)
     INTO numMaterials
     FROM item_material_h
        WHERE fk_item = l_item_id;    --Does NOT like this line!!
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (numMaterials);
   
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference particular column, i.e.

```
WHERE fk_item = l_item_id.id;
```

because of

```
CURSOR item_id_cur IS select id from item_h
                             --
                             this
```

---

Alternatively, you could have declared

```
l_item_id item_h.id%type;          --> note ".id%type"!
```

and then use it as you already did:

```
FETCH item_id_cur INTO l_item_id;
(...)       

WHERE fk_item = l_item_id;
```

Don't forget to **close** the cursor!

---

Another option you might be interested in is a cursor FOR loop which is simpler than the one you used because Oracle does *many* things instead of you: you don't have to explicitly declared cursor (just put select statement into the loop) nor cursor variable, open nor close the cursor nor worry about exiting the loop:

```
declare
  numMaterials number;
begin
  for item_id_cur in (select id from item_h where value = 'myvalue') loop
    select count(*) into numMaterials
      from item_material_h
      where fk_item = item_id_cur.id;
    dbms_output.put_line(numMaterials);
  end loop;
end;
```